# Query items in nested dictionaries with wildcards

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, wildcard

I am trying to retrieve items in nested dictionaries and print them out for a text game coded with Python 3 with WILDCARDs.

Here is the dictionary:

```
dict = {
    "Ninja1": {
        "no": "there is a map under the blue rock"
    },
    "amy": {
        "yes": "the peasant's name is Ato"
    }
}
```

I would like to loop through the dictionary and print strings (like: 'there is a map..) IF its key is 'yes'.

```
for key in dict:
    if dict[WILDCARD] == 'yes':
        print (dict[WILDCARD]['yes'])
```

I am new at this, so I'm sure the codes are horrible.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a name; you are masking the built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is test for the presence of a key; use the `in` operator:

```
for key in yourdict:
    if 'yes' in yourdict[key]:
        print(yourdict[key]['yes'])
```

Comment: to Martijn Pieters: funny thing, your avatar is a ninja and my text game has ninjas in it haha. THANKS! your codes work like a charm!